# Converting normal attoparsec parser code to conduit/pipe based

Tags: parsing, haskell, conduit, attoparsec, haskell-pipes

I have written a following parsing code using `attoparsec`:

```
data Test = Test {
  a :: Int,
  b :: Int
  } deriving (Show)

testParser :: Parser Test
testParser = do
  a <- decimal
  tab
  b <- decimal
  return $ Test a b

tParser :: Parser [Test]
tParser =  many' $ testParser <* endOfLine
```

This works fine for small sized files, I execute it like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  text <- TL.readFile "./testFile"
  let (Right a) = parseOnly (manyTill anyChar endOfLine *> tParser) text
  print a
```

But when the size of the file is greater than 70MB, it consumes tons of memory. As a solution, I thought I would use `attoparsec-conduit`. After going through their [API](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.1.0.4/docs/Data-Conduit-Attoparsec.html), I'm not sure how to make them work together. My parser has the type `Parser Test` but it's `sinkParser` actually accepts parser of type `Parser a b`. I'm interested in how to execute this parser in constant memory ? (A pipes based solution is also acceptable, but I'm not used to the Pipes API.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first type parameter to `Parser` is just the data type of the input (either `Text` or `ByteString`). You can provide your `testParser` function as the argument to `sinkParser` and it will work fine. Here's a short example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import           Conduit                 (liftIO, mapM_C, runResourceT,
                                          sourceFile, ($$), (=$))
import           Data.Attoparsec.Text    (Parser, decimal, endOfLine, space)
import           Data.Conduit.Attoparsec (conduitParser)

data Test = Test {
  a :: Int,
  b :: Int
  } deriving (Show)

testParser :: Parser Test
testParser = do
  a <- decimal
  space
  b <- decimal
  endOfLine
  return $ Test a b

main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT
     $ sourceFile "foo.txt"
    $$ conduitParser testParser
    =$ mapM_C (liftIO . print)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the `pipes` solution (assuming that you are using a `Text`-based parser):

```
import Pipes
import Pipes.Text.IO (fromHandle)
import Pipes.Attoparsec (parsed)
import qualified System.IO as IO

main = IO.withFile "./testfile" IO.ReadMode $ \handle -> runEffect $
    for (parsed (testParser <* endOfLine) (fromHandle handle)) (lift . print)
```